# Why can I do 4K@60Hz over HDMI on some monitors but not others?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport

I have a new M1 MacBook Pro 14". I also have two 4K monitors. One is a 32" Samsung [S32R750UEN](https://www.samsung.com/us/business/support/owners/product/sr750-series-s32r750uen/) bought about two years ago. The other is a 28" Samsung [LU28E570DS](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/uhd-and-wqhd/28-ue570-uhd-monitor-lu28e570ds-za/) bought two days ago. The MacBook has no problem driving the older monitor at the full 4K@60Hz using this [Anker adapter](https://us.anker.com/collections/adapters/products/a8312?variant=37438304157846) and HDMI, but the same machine, with the same adapter, and the same HDMI cable, steadfastly refuses to drive the newer monitor at 4K@60Hz -- as in, it's not even an option in Display Prefs and EasyRes doesn't show any options for it either.

I've seen a number of posts that suggest that 4K@60Hz requires a USB-C to DisplayPort cable, and that it won't work over HDMI. I guess I could buy that explanation if I didn't have the older monitor as an example of 4K@60Hz working over HDMI. What gives? Why does it work with one monitor and not with the other?

Comment: What HDMI version does the one implement vs the other?  Also, why in the world would you use HDMP if DP is an option?

Comment: Leaving the question here in case anyone has any insights, but I did order the USB-C to DP cable and that solved all my problems. I just didn't have one on hand when I posted the question.

Comment: Never use HDMI if you have any other option.